# Star Wars the clone wars episode where Anakin & Ahsoka meet?

Tags: star-wars, episode-identification, the-clone-wars

I am trying to watch the series but can't find the episode when Anakin  meets Ahsoka. I can find bits of it but not the full episode.

Comment: StarWars.com has a chronological listing of "The Clone Wars" - it includes the film -http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder

Answer (score 6):

That happened in the very first episode, which also happens to be known as *The Clone Wars* movie.*
Here it is on IMDb - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185834/

*(And by "very first", I mean the one that comes first according to airdate. But *The Clone Wars* had a really crazy airing schedule compared to the chronological order of the episodes, so in the movie actually takes place several episodes in if you're following the correct timeline as given by StarWars.com.)

Comment: I would dispute that it is the first chronological episode.  It was the first one aired, but the events of a few episodes happened prior to the events of the movie

Comment: Oh yes, so sorry, I meant it was the first one by release date. Not chronological. I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 3):

They meet during the events of the [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(film)) film, which was produced as a theatrical film and from which the TV series was created.

Depending on which collection you buy, this will either exist as a stand-alone film, or be split into episodes.

Essentially you can think of Ashoka and Anakin meeting in Season 1, Episode 1.

Comment: Oh hey, looked at that. We answered at the same time. XD Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @ElvenPadawan You will delete your answer. _waves hand all Jedi-like_

Comment: fwiw - it doesn't show it now, but Tim's answer was first by two minutes

Comment: @NKCampbell I actually was typing first, but he used his Jedi-speed powers and got his answer posted before I could hit the submit button. He also went back and edited several times after publishing his initial question. Which I'm not at all trying to find a problem with! He did get his published first, so kudos to him and his typing abilities!